# What does the Quality value indicate?

Tags: you-must-build-a-boat

As you add Quests before running it changes the 'quality' value of the level you are about to run.

What difference does this make? Is there a correlation to the amount of gold monsters hold, or the frequency of certain tiles to match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It increases the amount of gold or valuable items you find during your run.

Adding more quests will increase both quality (gold found) and danger (monster toughness), sometimes even adding negative effects to the level. If you are having problems with a certain quest, try to quit and restart it with less quests at the same time.